# Applying mod operator on large integer

Tags: random, integer, fortran, long-integer

I am generating large integers in my fortran code which are used as seed to random number function I'm using. The problem is that I have several of those, and I noticed that sometime the generated numbers are too big and simply get `2147483647` which, to my understanding is the 8 digit limit of integer in fortran.

I want to solve this by taking the mod of my number with that limit. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Most Fortran compilers provide 64-bit integers which will provide at least 18 decimal digits.  (Fortran 2008 requires that 64-bit integers be supported.)  You can select these via:

```
integer, parameter :: VeryLongInt_K = selected_int_kind (18)
integer (kind=VeryLongInt_K) :: variable
```

or you can use the `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV` and the `int64` type to select 64-bit integers:

```
use, intrinsic :: ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
integer (int64) :: variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use larger integer kind.

```
integer, parameter :: ip = selected_int_kind(number_of_digits_you_need)
integer(ip) :: var !all the integer variables that need to be large
```

The integers will be able to have larger values and the `mod` function will generate results of the same kind.

Comment: Of course `number_of_digits_you_need` should really be `number_of_digits_you_need_within_the_limits_of_the_compiler`.  Arbitrarily writing `selected_int_kind(85)` (for example) is not guaranteed to deliver an integer with 85 decimal digits.

Comment: Of course. But there may be compiler with such a kind in the future. 38 is a value one could expect to work on some systems.